# Linq to Entities - is count() clever enough to send a group by clause to the DB

Tags: linq-to-entities, group-by

This is surprisingly difficult to find, and as I am an amateur using express edition of VS, I don't believe I can see the SQL being sent to the DB (although happy to be corrected).

If I want the total number of records in a database with simple select, for example

```
(From f in _db.Foo
 Where f.Bar> 3
 Select f).Count();
```

Will linq to entities automatically generate an SQL group by and count clause - so that the only data sent between the db server and the .net application is a single integer (or long int) value, or should i implement this myself by manipulating the linq to entities query?

Thank you

Comment: "I don't believe I can see the SQL being sent to the DB (although happy to be corrected)" - Correction: Use Entity Framework Profiler:  http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the group by and count will be included in the generated SQL.

Your query can be a bit more succinct: `_db.Foo.Count(f => f.Bar > 3)` will do the same thing.

I recommend using [LNQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for testing out your queries and improving your LINQ skills.